# How do you describe a young woman who, while pretty when seen from behind, is ugly when seen from the front?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a term, a phrase or an idiomatic expression to describe a young woman who, while pretty when seen from behind, is ugly, if not repulsive, when seen from the front?

After some searches I focused my attention on "double-faced woman", but I'm unsure whether this is the best expression one can think of.

Comment: A *butterface*.  Everything's hot but her face.

Comment: @ninja, do you mean that "butterface" is derived from "but-her-face"?

Comment: Since it's in Wikitionary, it must be true.  See my answer below.

Comment: Folks, why downvotes? I'm writing an interesting essay whose leading character is a young woman who never takes off her burqa.

Comment: If it is in english I would write bakku-shan in italics since its the exact definition of what you are trying to convey.

Comment: A Mexican friend of mine once told me they use the term "shrimp" - the body is good, but the head is useless.

Comment: I downvoted because it looked like trolling for slang like "butterface", which is very insulting to women. Downvote cancelled.

Comment: @JeffSahol -- it sounds like he was *genuinely* looking for "butterface".

Comment: If she "never takes off her burqa", how does anyone know what she looks like from the front?

Comment: @Trevor D, in the story the young woman, an Islamic living in the U.S., is sure of being a "butterface" and, as such, she has a fear of being viewed her face, but, at the end, when she takes off her burqa, an American man falls in love with her, enchantend from her Arab face.

Comment: *She had a back that launched a thousand ships.*

Comment: @atsutoNagatomo I think 'black swan' is the right nomenclature, given what you describe. See the story of The Black Swan

Comment: I think I've heard the heteronormative (and sexist(?)) "woman from the back, man in the front"

Comment: Easy question: *She's one-sided*

Comment: @DjinTonic One side of the body is not usually the back and the front.

Answer (score 10):

A *[butterface](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butterface)*:

### Etymology 1

> Contraction of "but her face" (as in: "Everything about her is great, ... but her face.").

### Noun

butterface (plural butterfaces)

> (slang) A woman who has an attractive body but less attractive facial features.

Comment: We use butterface in my region as a girl who is otherwise skinny or average but has a chubby face.

Answer (score 2):

***PRAWN***,
 according to [Internet Slang](http://www.internetslang.com/PRAWN-meaning-definition.asp), means exactly:

> Girl who is good looking except for her face

I have never heard of this expression, but [shrimps](http://saltfishing.about.com/od/baitsandlures/tp/How-To-Hook-A-Live-Shrimp-With-A-Jig-Head.htm) (sometimes called prawns) swim backwards, which might explain the etymology of this uncomplimentary expression.

> Shrimp normally swim backwards when they move fast. They crawl forward
>   or move forward slowly my manoeuvring their flippers and feet, but
>   when they move quickly, they kick backwards.

I found a more *reliable* reference for "prawn" in [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=prawn.)

<sub>(I corrected spelling and other minor punctuation mistakes)</sub>

> To describe a chick that has a mad body, but a bad face. It comes from
>   when you eat a prawn, you eat the body and throw away the head ...
>
> (Australian) person 1: *Man, did u end up hookin up with that chick?*
>   person 2: *Yeah, but she was a bit of a prawn tho'*

Answer (score 2):

From comment box,

> I'm writing an interesting essay whose leading character is a young
>   woman who never takes off her burqa [...] the young woman, an Islamic
>   living in the U.S., is sure of being a "butterface" and, as such, she
>   has a fear of being viewed her face, but [...] when she takes off her
>   burqa, an American man falls in love with her, enchanted from her
>   Arab face

Taking into consideration the OP's comments it appears he is not really interested in a term which describes a woman being attractive from behind and whose facial features are unpleasant. Instead, he is writing an essay about a woman who *thinks* she has an unattractive (ugly) face.

The additional information demands a more suitable word for an essay/story, especially as I seriously doubt a Muslim woman, born outside the USA, would be aware of the American slang words;  *butter face* or *prawn* which are both highly derogatory. No woman, I know of, would ever describe herself in those terms.

Hence, I would suggest the more appropriate [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+plain+Jane), ***a plain Jane***, *a woman or girl who is not attractive*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the word

> **Gorgon**

The [most famous gorgon is Medusa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgon).  often mis-portrayed in recent films, Medusa actually has tremendous beauty; the curse was to add this hideousness that caused death to mortals.  All the Gorgons have this quality.

It's maybe 'leveraged', but you could think of any beautiful thing that has a *surprise-ugliness* as a **gorgon**.

Since gorgons are powerful creatures, this term could be appropriate to the heroine of a story.

---

FWIW, I do not think there is a non-derogatory word for this, since the judgement of ugliness is inherent in all such terms. If you want a **non-judgemental**, the closest I can think is

> Black Swan

I.E.: Appears ugly, but has a hidden beauty that emerges.

But, this is the opposite of what you asked, which is that the beauty is seen first, the ugliness later.  By compare, Medusa's beauty was recognized by mortals only after she was dead.

Answer (score 1):

> [Well, helloooo from the neck down...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYZO5HY-_eQ)
>
> —Zap Branagan

The most common is going to be CornbreadNinja's **[butterface](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/125709/171986)**, although increasingly few people understand that it comes from '...but her face' and just process it as *butter* + *face*. You've got posters within this thread already who misunderstand it that way. The ones who *do* understand it consider it sexist, some within this thread finding it offensively downvote-worthily so. There's no way around that: Your question is completely based on [the male gaze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Male_gaze), which is quintessentially (even definitionally) sexist.

Mari-Lou A's **[prawn](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/125772/171986)** and Mike G's **shrimp** are much worse, of course, since the visual image is wishing you could entirely remove the head to eat the meat.

Some dated British slang for this idea is **[BOBFOC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BOBFOC#English)**: 'Body off *[Baywatch](https://www.ecranlarge.com/uploads/image/001/116/xr3wk0ohzfavojxsh7g78ycqvqp-728.jpg)*, Face off *[Crimewatch](https://www.nwemail.co.uk/resources/images/10442250?type=responsive-gallery-fullscreen)*'. It has the benefit of being more gender neutral but neither show is terribly relevant these days and [Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=GB&q=BOBFOC) and [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=BOBFOC&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) both show the term tapering off since 2010.

Similarly dated [AAVE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) slang on the other side of the pond is **[tip drill](http://slack-time.com/music-video-2717-nelly-tip-drill)**, which started off as a poetic comparison of a [basketball training regimen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5woJdVrHdo8) with gangbanging. [Nelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelly)'s catchy [2007 song on the subject](http://slack-time.com/music-video-2717-nelly-tip-drill), though, became far more popular than the slang it was based on. The refrain 'It must be ya ass || 'cause it ain't ya face' fully shifted the meaning to 'someone more visually pleasing from behind'. That said, even though its video is now considered a classic in its genre, it is over 10 years old now. [Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=US&q=tip%20drill) and [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tip+drill&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) both show use has fallen off, albeit less than BOBFOC has.

Besides those, there are a ton of variants on **paper bags** & **brown bags**—*paperbagger*, *two-bagger*, *brown bag special*, &c.—all referencing the idea that the person would be more appealing if they were wearing a paper bag over their head. The noun forms are much less common than the verbs, but some reference to the idea would certainly come into play if your immigrant is living in the US.

*Pretty from afar but far from pretty* is well phrased enough to at least mention, but anyone saying it to your heroine isn't going to be well received.

Answer (score 0):

A slang term would be **brunt**.  The japanese have an exact word for it bakku-shan.

Brunt meaning everything ugly in front.  Butterface is a good substitute but points out that she has an ugly/chubby face which might not be the case.

Comment: Please provide a reference for your answer.

Comment: Still needs a reference & also doesn't quite make sense. OP _is_ saying it is the case that they're ugly from the front. Butterface also doesn't actually have anything to do with butter or chubbiness, although both may be involved.

Answer (score -1):

Consider **[ugly duckling](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ugly-duckling)**

> a person or thing, initially ugly or unpromising, that changes into something beautiful or admirable